# pass all elements of the array to a single array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having a problem obtaining this output. I have an array declared like this :

```
$category = array(1,2,4,5,10); //category_ids
```

Now, I want to pass it to another parameter just like this:

```
$parameter = array(
         array('category_id' => 1),
         array('category_id' => 2),
         array('category_id' => 4),
         .
         .
         . 
);
```

How to do this?

Comment: What is your expected behaviuor? `$category` is a single array.

Comment: I just want the the variable parameter to have a contents like that based on the values of variable category. This paramter is then passed on to the api

Comment: You don't "pass arrays to a parameter", that's just nonsense. Do you mean you want to construct a new array from the old array?

Answer (score 1):

Like This:

```
<?php
$category = array(1,2,4,5,10); //category_ids

foreach($category as $c){
    $parameter[] = array('category_id' => $c);
}

print_r($parameter);

// Output:
//Array ( [0] => Array ( [category_id] => 1 ) 
//[1] => Array ( [category_id] => 2 ) 
//[2] => Array ( [category_id] => 4 ) 
//[3] => Array ( [category_id] => 5 ) 
//[4] => Array ( [category_id] => 10 ) )
```

?

Comment: Thanks! this solves my problem. I really need to review my accessing. haha.